# How to find Quartiles from the data in two columns in excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, quartile

Hi I have a basic question. I tried to find the answer by myself but I couldn't. how to contain multi areas in Quartile func in excel? (actually, google spreadsheet)

I know the basic func of quartile is =quartile(data,1). ex) =quartile(A2:A10,1)

Situation: I have a # of trials in column A, and the # of scores in column B. After I had 50 trials, I didn't want the table to be too long. so I have another # of trials in column D(51~100) and # of scores in column E

Main point: I want to find the average, median, and qurtile1, quartile2, quartile3 for all scores of my trials.
I know for average, =average(B2:B51,E2:E51). for median, =median(B2:B51,E2:E51). However, when I do quartile =quartile(B2:B51,E2:E51,1) or =quartile((B2:B51,E2:E51),1) it has an error that I put 3 data and it should be 2. How can I contain the data from two columns?(column B and column E) please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Range *unions* in `Excel` are achieved by the following syntax:

`(Range1,Range2)`

For example:

`=QUARTILE((B2:B51,E2:E51),1)`

Whereas in `Google Sheets` it's:

`{Range1;Range2}`

For example:

`=QUARTILE({Range1;Range2},1)`